# Powershell output with path and hash

Tags: powershell, hash

i have the following requirements:
i have copied several thousand files to a new server and now need to nuke the original server. but its imperitive these records are intact, hence the need to hash (SHA1 is fine).

This is what i have so far:

```
$ctr = 1000000
gci -Path X:\1999 -Recurse -File -Force | Where-Object {(
    $_.extension-match "xxx" -or
    $_.extension-match "Z[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]")} | Select-Object @{
        Name = "ID' ; Expression={(([ref]$ctr).Value++ }},Fullname
```

But now i want to add the SHA1 HASH to my output but stuck... i have tried the following:

```
$x = 1000000
gci -Path X:\1999 -Recurse -File -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 | Where-Object {(
    $_.extension-match "xxx" -or
    $_.extension-match 'Z[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]' | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 | Select-Object @{
        Name = 'ID' ; Expression={(([ref]$x).Value++) }},Fullname, Hash
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My next step will be to take the fullname find the same file on the new server and compare... (while outputting to a file ;-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Love the Nuke comment given your handle. A favorite move quote:

> I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only
> way to be sure.

At any rate, there is no extension property on the PSCustomObject generated by Get-FileHash. If you are trying to add the hash string to the object then you can do that with a `Select-Object` command.  Might look something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\1999 -Recurse -File -Force | 
Where-Object{ $_.extension-match "xxx" -or $_.extension-match 'Z[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]' } |
Select-Object *,@{ Name = 'Hash'; Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash }}
```

Note: I'm not sure what you are doing with `$ctr` or `$x`.  If you are using sequential numbers to assign an ID property maybe just use a typical For loop assigning the value of the iteration variable.

If the intent is to use the ID to cross reference and compare files it may be error prone.  You cannot guarantee the files will be listed by `Get-ChildItem` in the same order, so comparing hashes will likely fail.  You may be able to use a `Compare-Object` command to see which hashes are missing from the destination server, and even subsequently copy the file.  Honestly, even a `Where-Object` would facilitate that.

Tell me more about the source and destination.  Also what's the actual workflow.  Happy to add more demo...